# Error installing Jekyll

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, installation, jekyll

I'm getting an error every time I try to install Jekyll here is some of my output from terminal -

```
moooobile:~ usr$ gem install jekyll

ERROR:  While executing gem ... (Gem::FilePermissionError)
    You don't have write permissions for the /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0 directory.
```

I've already installed `rbenv` and changed PATH to:

```
moooobile:~ usr$ echo $PATH

/usr/local/bin:/usr/local/sbin:~/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/opt/X11/bin
```

Could anyone give me any tips as to what could be wrong?

Comment: How did you install ruby? It sounds like you used `sudo`, which is not right.

Comment: Installed it with homebrew.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to reinstall Ruby with correct permissions. Consult [rbenv readme](https://github.com/sstephenson/rbenv#installing-ruby-versions) about installing rubies. Also, you need to create a .ruby-version file in your project directory to ensure loading of correct ruby version. More about it in [command reference](https://github.com/sstephenson/rbenv#command-reference) in the same readme.

Comment: Fixed! You were right about the permissions needing to be set and creating a .ruby-version file.